# Mapping two app service to one DNS in azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I have two app services. One for UI and one for web api. I need to create a DNS so that I should be able to access like www.example.com/ui and www.example.com/api. Please let me know anyone how to achieve this without virtual directory concept.

Thanks

Comment: I think you're looking for the concept of a "Reverse Proxy". Take a look at API Management in the Azure Portal. It's able to route requests of endpoints to different 'internal' systems.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve this purely with DNS. DNS knows nothing about routes, only domain names. So `www.example.com` must resolve to one service, which should be your reverse proxy, maybe Application Gateway?

Here's the tutorial on hosting two apps behind Application Gateway: [Tutorial: Create an application gateway that hosts multiple web sites using the Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/tutorial-multiple-sites-cli).

> Multiple-site hosting enables you to configure more than one web site on the same application gateway instance. This feature allows you to configure a more efficient topology for your deployments by adding up to 20 web sites to one application gateway. Each web site can be directed to its own pool. For example, application gateway can serve traffic for `contoso.com` and `fabrikam.com` from two server pools called ContosoServerPool and FabrikamServerPool.